# Can author's edit each others entries within Membergroup

Tags: members

I've got a couple of channels. One is a Standard channel. There are multiple Member groups. Each with their own part they can edit, but most entries belong to the Standard channel. 
Members can now edit all entries under Standard. Als the entries not belonging to them.
Is it possible for members to edit the entries belonging to one of their Member's?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Look under **Members → Member Groups → Edit Member Group** - there's a section called **Channel Posting Privileges**. There is a setting there which determines whether members in a group can edit other members' entries in whatever channels they have access to called *Can edit entries authored by others*.

[image: Channel Posting Privileges]

Comment: Hi Derek. I'm aware of this. This option gives the members privileges to edit all the entries within the channel. I'm looking for something like "Can edit entries authored by others in this Membergroup"

Comment: Ah, I see. Not aware of an option like this, no.